# How to obtain the row number from the set when searching for the maximum value?

Tags: r

I have this file `P.P0.1.txt`:

```
4
4
4
4
5
6
4
6
7
7
```

when I use:

```
> max(P.P0.1$V1])
[1] 7
```

I get the answer `7`. How to get the line numbers (here lines 9 and 10) with the maximum values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `which` to accomplish this:

```
vec<-scan('P.P0.1.txt')
which(vec==max(vec))
```

or if you do not mind getting only the first match:

```
which.max(vec)
```